# Change the example environment

Tags: math-mode

At the moment I use this definition of example:

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
```

How can I put a line break after in a automatic way after the number of the example (header)? Basically I don't want that my example starts in the same line of the header of the example but on the next line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you load `amsthm`. Hee is a simple code to define an `example` theorem style:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\newtheoremstyle{example}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{\smallskip}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{example}
    This is an illuminating example. This is an illuminating example. This is an illuminating example. This is an illuminating example.
\end{example}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You light also consider using `ntheorem`. It has special styles for what you want.

Comment: I know (actually I'm a user of ntheorem, personally), but the O.P. clearly uses amsthm. `Thmtools` would also has led to a less cryptic code, and it cooperates with both amsthm and ntheorem.

Comment: Yes `Thmtools` is a very nice alternative. I just wanted to point out the simplicity of the `ntheorem` syntax.

Comment: I fully agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

You might also consider using `ntheorem`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem,lipsum}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```